# Question about android: I Want to upload images to server

Tags: android, service, upload, android-activity

Helllo

I am trying to upload some images to the server. If i placed the code in the subclass of activity, will the sending be interrupted by the onPause function when the user leaving the activity while the user want to use other application. 
If this is the problem would it be better to use service to upload the file instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best best is to use an AsyncTask.  This will execute in the background and give any feedback on the UI thread if you need.